# JavaScript Type Errors in console

Tags: jsp, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am using Icefaces 3.2 and I get some errors and warnings when I use the below XML standards. My file type is `xhtml`. I don't know if I am missing something here.

```
TypeError: ice.fixViewState is not a function
TypeError: ice.captureEnterKey is not a function
Warning: Non-standard document.all property was used. Use W3C standard
document.getElementById() instead.



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root version="2.1" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
```

Comment: If working with Facelets, then you don't need any of `<jsp>` tags.

Comment: I removed all `jsp` tags but I still see those errors, anything else that you think I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the latest version of `Icefaces 3.3` to fix the issues.